# Setting javascript variable and then trying to use Alert but getting empty message

Tags: jquery

I wrote some simple code :

```
var tm='<input type="checkbox" name="city[]" />';

tm=$(tm).val('2');

alert($(tm).text()); // <--- it does not have internal text so how do i see itself?
```

but when im alerting it alert me empty message.

I want to see :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="city[]"  value="2"/>
```

**in the ALERT**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `.html()`.

```
alert($("<div>").append(tm).html());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z4AHG/

Comment: That won't work either. The input element has no children and the element itself is not included.

Answer (score 0):

I found it

```
var tm='<input type="checkbox" name="city[]" />';

tm=$(tm).val('2');

alert( $('<div>').append(          tm.clone()              ).remove().html());
```

Comment: `.remove()` is unnecessary. The `div` element is not part of the DOM tree anyway.

Comment: @Felix Kling , I think it would be safer , since I can attache an event to the element , and i want to remove EVERYTHING

Comment: @Royi: It depends on what you want to do with the jQuery object... passing it to jQuery again is definitely not needed.

Comment: @Felix Kling I Talked about the `.clone` - , I asked if you thought it is necessary

Comment: @RoyiNamir: And I'm saying it depends on the context. If the element is already part of the DOM, then yes, `clone` would be necessary as you otherwise remove it from the its current location. In your situation here, it is not necessary.